Autocad top/bottom overlapping blocks
how can autocad determine which block is on top between 2 overlapping blocks? Which attribute is that based on?
Can I somehow leverage that information in python using ezdxf when comparing 2 block_refs?
(block_refs is a list that we get by the folllowing code: block_refs = list(doc.query('INSERT'))
where doc is the dxf file read by ezdxf.readfile)
I tried to use the insertion points of these elements but this is obviously wrong. when having two elements on the same layer where one appears on top of the other, I was wondering which information is the one that autocad uses to determine which block to show on top

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

The redraw order of DXF entities in a layout is in ascending handle order. When new entities are created, the entity handles are incremented and the redraw order is in most cases the same as the creation order.
There is a mechanism to override the redraw order.  Each LAYOUT entity can define a mapping from the entity-handle to a redraw-handle, and the entities are drawn in the ascending order of the redraw-handles.  This mapping is stored in the SORTENTSTABLE entity, which is attachted to the layout via the ACAD_SORTENTS entry in the LAYOUT entity's extension dictionary.
This code generates the entities of a layout in drawing order, see also reorder-module:
from ezdxf import reorder

def entities_in_drawing_order(layout):
    handle_mapping = list(layout.get_redraw_order())
    if handle_mapping:
        return reorder.ascending(layout, handle_mapping)
    return iter(layout)


The HEADER variable $SORTENTS does also something - but I don't care ;).

For others stumbling upon the code, layout refers to any ezdxf layout object of your file. For example I used doc.modelspace (where doc is the variable where the loaded file is stored, i.e. doc = ezdxf.load(filename))

or rtfm https://ezdxf.mozman.at/docs/
